# Have Selected Dropdown Appear on Edit Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, select, dropdown, razor-pages

NOTE: REVISED FROM ORIGINAL POST. SOME OF THE MODEL/PROPERTY names have changed with more editing.

I have a create page which will utilizes a couple of dropdown lists. For the edit page, I would like the selected value from the create page to appear as the selected dropdown choice, but would still like it to be a dropdown list of all values so that users could select a new value if the value selected on the create page was incorrect.

For example, if a user selected 'peaches' from a dropdown list of 'apples', 'peaches' and 'pears' on the create page and posted it, when they go to the edit page, I would like the dropdown list to show 'peaches', as the selected value, but allow the user to pick 'apples' or 'pears' if they wished to change it.

Here is what I have on my edit.cshtml page for my dropdown lists (both are set up the same way):

```
<td style="width: 25%">
   <div class="mb-3">
      <label asp-for="InfoSite.Specialty"></label>
      <select asp-for="InfoSite.Specialty" id="Select1" class="form-select"> 
         <option value="">---Select Specialty---</option>
         @foreach(var item in Model.DisplayMDSpecialtyData)
             {
               <option value="@item.ID" selected="@(item.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.Specialty?true:false)" disabled="@(item.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.Specialty?true:false)">@item.Description</option>
             }
       </select>
   </div>
</td>
<td style="width: 25%">
   <div class="mb-3">
       <label asp-for="InfoSite.ResType"></label>                      
       <select asp-for="InfoSite.ResType" id="Select2" class="form-select">
           <option value="">---Select Residence Type---</option>
           @foreach(var item in Model.DisplayResTypeData)
              {
                 <option value="@item.ID" selected="@(item.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.ResType?true:false)" disabled="@(item.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.ResType?true:false)">@item.Description</option>
              }
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

And here is what I have on my edit.cshtml.cs (includes info for the 2 dropdowns):

```
namespace PHECWeb.Pages.InfoSites;

[BindProperties]

public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public InfoSite InfoSite { get; set; }
    public EditModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ResType> DisplayResTypeData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MDSpecialty> DisplayMDSpecialtyData { get; set;  }

    public async void OnGet(int? ID)
    {
        InfoSite = _db.InfoSite.Find(ID);
        DisplayResTypeData = await _db.ResType.ToListAsync();
        DisplayMDSpecialtyData = await _db.MDSpecialty.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.InfoSite.Update(InfoSite);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Site Information updated successfully.";
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

I am getting the dreaded System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on the @foreach(var item in Model.DisplayMDSpecialtyData).

[image: System.NullReferenceException Error]

I desperately need help to get past this. :( Would someone please be able to add some insight (in layman's terms as I am a newbie to all of this) as to what edits I would need to this code to rid myself of this error? I have Googled and YouTubed, but because my knowledge level is so low at this point, I don't understand much of what I am seeing. I understand the concept, I just don't understand the placement of a fix (view vs .cs) or the exact syntax of a fix. Trying my best to learn and as stated above, asking the question was only after MUCH searching on my own. Please be kind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was another stumper with a very simple change to make the code work.

```
<option value="@item.ID" selected="@(item.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.Specialty?true:false)" disabled="@(item.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.Specialty?true:false)">@item.Description</option>
```

Just needed the "disabled=..." removed to look like this:

```
<option value="@item.ID" selected="@(item.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.Specialty?true:false)">@item.Description</option>
```

And then the selected value displays on the Edit page just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the following things:

Firstly, by using your current code your `select` will generate the option value which match the `ID` value and the option text which match the `Description` value.

```
<select>
    <option value="ID1">Description1</option>
    <option value="ID2">Description2</option>
    //....
</select>
```

Then the `asp-for="InfoSite.ResType"` matches the selected option value which is the `ID` value of `ResCategory`. So you need be sure the value of `ResType` and `ID` should keep same.

Finally, for the Edit page, If the `InfoSite.ResType`'s value is same with one of the option value(`ID` value). The dropdownlist will automatically make this option selected. But the `disabled` cannot do like this way.

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Model

```
public class ResCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
public class InfoSite
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? ResType { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<select asp-for="InfoSite.ResType" id="Select2" class="form-select">
    <option value="">---Select Residence Type---</option>
    @foreach(var item in Model.DisplayResCatData)
    {
        <option value="@item.ID" selected="@(item.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.ResType?true:false)" disabled="@(item.ID.ToString()==Model.InfoSite.ResType?true:false)">@item.Description</option>
    }
</select>
```

PageModel

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ResCategory> DisplayResCatData { get; set; }
    public InfoSite InfoSite { get; set; }
    public void OnGet(int? id)
    {
        //for easy testing, I just hard coded here......
        //InfoSite = await _db.InfoSite.FindAsync(id);
        InfoSite = new InfoSite()
        {
            ID = 1,
            ResType = "2"
        };
        DisplayResCatData = new List<ResCategory>()
        {
            new ResCategory(){ID=1,Description="aa"},
            new ResCategory(){ID=2,Description="bb"},
            new ResCategory(){ID=3,Description="cc"}
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rena, Thanks for the explanation. I'm afraid I can follow along until the page model and then I get lost. You say //for easy testing, just hard coded here..., but how do I get the Description values from the ResCategory database to post to the InfoSite database? I don't want to hardcode values as users will be updating the ResCategory database and adding to that dropdown list. I want this to all happen automatically. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MelB, `await _db.ResCategory.select(a=>a.Description).ToListAsync();` can get `Description` values from the `ResCategory` database.

Comment: I am using the above code as you suggest, but am getting an error when running the program. The program stops on the @foreach(var item in Model.DisplayResCatData) (in the page view) with the Model.DisplayResCatData highlighted and presents the error: System.NullReference.Exception: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' I'm not sure what I might be missing?

Comment: Hi @MelB,  That is because `Model.DisplayResCatData` is null value. You need set breakpoint and check your `Model.DisplayResCatData` if it contains any data.

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of ? was to eliminate null value errors?

Comment: I set a  breakpoint on the line with the Model.DisplayResCatData, but how do I see if it contains any data? I hover over it, but it does not show me anything. Sorry, very, very, new to this.

Comment: I right clicked on the Model.DisplayResCatData and did a "Quick Watch". That displayed a different error: CS0103 - The name 'DisplayResCatData' does not exist in the current context.